# Linux KVM: Troubleshooting dropped packets on a Windows Guest

Tags: windows, networking, kvm-virtualization, linux-kernel

virsh 0.9.10 Enterprise Linux 6.3
I have a Windows 7 guest running on the KVM host and am frequently seeing 25% loss when pinging other boxes on the same subnet.  The first ping request times out, and the others usually succeed.  How would I go about troubleshooting possible packet drop or errors on a Windows guest?  I did ifconfig on the KVM host and see no dropped or error packets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just some thoughts:

1. disable tso and lso on the host
2. set the bridge `DELAY=0`
3. use the virtio network card in the VM
4. If bonding is in use, try a different mode

Comment: I would love to hear some more in depth explanations for those 4 suggestions if you don't mind.

Comment: 1. buggy drivers, especially bnx2 in conjunction with some bcom firmware versions can cause weird issues. 2. This is especially important with live migration, but if a VM comes up and down often, it can also play a role in a network coming up in time. 3. this is best practice, virtio is PV and performs much better than e1000/rtl. 4. some bonding modes are known to not work with bridges at all (0 and 6), others, have been observed to cause network issues with different switches